# GNU Screen tab titles all just 'zsh'

Tags: amazon-ec2, putty, gnu-screen, oh-my-zsh

OK, so I want to start by first explaining my setup. I have a windows desktop at home, and I am SSH'ing into an Amazon EC2 instance (via PuTTY) running Amazon Linux. I have zsh as my default shell, and oh-my-zsh installed as well. This "cloud developer desktop" model works well for me, but I am having one problem that I have poured more time into than I care to admit: GNU screen only shows 'zsh' as the title of every tab. This is despite using oh-my-zsh's screen plugin (which I think isn't doing anything). Anyone able to help me out? I'd love to have something more descriptive in the tab, perhaps just the last x characters of the current directory (or an open file name if one is open in vim).

Like many screen users, I've had what I'm asking for before, but on a new rig now and don't fully understand everything in my .screenrc:

```
# Many settings from https://gist.github.com/azitabh/7427682 and
# https://gist.github.com/joaopizani/2718397 and
# https://gist.github.com/ChrisWills/1337178

# Allow bold colors - necessary for some reason
attrcolor b ".I"

# Tell screen how to set colors. AB = background, AF=foreground
termcapinfo xterm "Co#256:AB=\E[48;5;%dm:AF=\E[38;5;%dm"

# Erase background with current bg color
defbce "on"

# Cache 30000 lines for scroll back
defscrollback 30000

# add tabs on bottom
caption always "%{= bb}%{+b w}%n %t %h %=%l %H %c"

# Very nice tabbed colored hardstatus line
#hardstatus string '%{= Kd} %{= Kd}%-w%{= Kr}[%{= KW}%n %t%{= Kr}]%{= Kd}%+w %-= %{KG} %H%{KW}|%{KY}%101`%{KW}|%D %M %d %Y%{= Kc} %C%A%{-}'
hardstatus alwayslastline "%-Lw%{= BW}%50>%n%f* %t%{-}%+Lw%<"

#Remove vim buffer from scrollback history after quitting
altscreen on

# special xterm hardstatus: use the window title.
#termcapinfo xterm 'hs:ts=\E]2;:fs=\007:ds=\E]2;screen\007'
#termcapinfo xterm 'hs:ts=\E]2;:fs=\007:ds=\E]1;screen\007'

# Enable 256 color term
term xterm-256color

# Enables use of shift-PgUp and shift-PgDn
termcapinfo xterm|xterms|xs|rxvt ti@:te@

# tell screen that xterm can switch to dark background and has function keys.
termcapinfo xterm 'VR=\E[?5h:VN=\E[?5l'
termcapinfo xterm 'k1=\E[11~:k2=\E[12~:k3=\E[13~:k4=\E[14~'
termcapinfo xterm 'kh=\E[1~:kI=\E[2~:kD=\E[3~:kH=\E[4~:kP=\E[H:kN=\E[6~'

# window numbering starts at 1 not 0
bind c screen 1
bind 0 select 10
screen 1

#allow mouse scrolling in screen
termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@

# Automatically detach on hangup.
autodetach on
```

I also tried adding this to my .zshrc, and it helps, but isn't quite what I want, as if you run ls, now your title is ls. Ie, not very informative. But maybe editing here is actually the right way to go:

```
# So screen tabs receive running process title
# preexec () {
#   echo -ne "\ek${1%% *}\e\\"
# }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question a bit here:

Replacing the line in the `preexec ()` function above with this helps:

```
echo -ne "\ek$(pwd)\e\\"
```

Would still be best to only grab the characters from the x-to-last '/' to the end though, replacing the initial string with '...'